# Security Measurements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, security

If any site has hacked means how much percent has said that the back end of that site database will be safe.

**How to prevent the SQL Tables from hackers and what are the suggestions for this type of issues?**

Comment: exact duplicate http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46497/security-measurements-on-sql-server please don't cross post

Comment: I didnt get any exact answer that'y i posted here

Answer (score 3):

> How to prevent the SQL Tables from hackers?

There are entire books written on this subject.  The first thing is to make sure that the user access to SQL Azure from their web software can only select, insert, and update.

Have different administrative software with a different user access for table create, table update, and row delete.

> How to enter those thousands of data manually?

Get a bunch of computers and hire temporary workers to key the data.

A journey of ten thousand database rows begins with a single entry.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Gilbert Le Blanc. As the db is in GB's now our team will do it manually what about if that will grow in TB's?.. And also i have one doubt if that db has been really with an attack our team will going to insert products related data only through admin panels and they wanted us to carry customer and orders related data as it is from tables then the virus might comes through those tables..

Comment: What are the possible attacks on Sql server and how to measure them and what are the steps that becomes my server safe.

Comment: Buy this book, or something equivalent.  http://www.amazon.com/HACKING-EXPOSED-WEB-APPLICATIONS-Edition/dp/0071740643